# Error while doing ListLogLogPlot

Tags: plotting, ticks, logarithmic-scale

I am using version 11.2.0 for Windows (32-bit) (September 11, 2017) and some strange error shows up when I try to do a ListLogLog plot:

```
ListLogLogPlot[Range[20]^3, Joined -> True]
```

The error is: "Tick specification must be a list or a function". How can I fix that?

Comment: Works fine on my 11.20 Windows 64 bit with no errors.

Comment: Works fine on Windows 10 *Mathematica* versions 10.4.1 and 12.0.

Comment: Works fine on V12.0 on Linux

Comment: Works fine on V12, OS X.

Comment: Any idea on a workaround for that version?